# Cannot understand error in Java 8 lambda comparator with generics

Tags: java, generics, lambda, java-8

This code is not written by me but by someone else in a JUnit test, and I just don't understand why `<Long>` must be placed  after `Comparator.` (note the `.`) and before the method name call.

My specific problem is the placing of the "generic type announce".

From my understanding of generics, it should be written `Array<Long>`, or `Comparator<Long>.reverseOrder()`, but not `Comparator. <Long> reverseOrder()`.

Why is this correct? (no java error) (this is the already existing code)

```
assertEquals(Comparator.<Long> reverseOrder().compare(Long.valueOf(1L), Long.valueOf(2L)));
```

And this isn't? (error: cannot resolve symbol "reverseOrder")

```
Comparator<Long>. reverseOrder().compare(Long.valueOf(1L), Long.valueOf(2L));
```

And this also isn't??!?!

```
Comparator.reverseOrder().compare(Long.valueOf(1L), Long.valueOf(2L));
```

Error:

```
The method compare(Comparable<? super Comparable<? super T>>,
Comparable<? super Comparable<? super T>>) in the type
Comparator<Comparable<? super Comparable<? super T>>> is not
applicable for the arguments (Long, Long).
```

Note that I think this error makes everything even harder to understand :( as it is extremely difficult to understand not *what* but *why* it doesn't like my code).

But why isn't the previous method applicable? I can see clearly that it is from this:

```
Comparator helpMePlease = Comparator.reverseOrder();
// or even: Comparator<Long> helpMePlease = Comparator.reverseOrder();
helpMePlease.compare(Long.valueOf(1L), Long.valueOf(2L));
```

Comment: `Comparator.reverseOrder().compare(Long.valueOf(1L), Long.valueOf(2L));` this will not work because `javac` can't infer the types (and this has been discussed here on So before). the first one is a *valid* java syntax, the second is not - this isn't really anything new

Comment: Ah @Eugene, you are right. Thanks you very much for the answer:). I didn't know tho how to search my problem, that's why i asked a new question (with as much detail as i could think of).

Thanks!